# Can't detect I2C sensor with long wire

Tags: raspberry-pi3, sensors

When I use long cable about 3 meters, my Raspberry PI can't detect i2c sensor.

I check my cable but it don't have any problem.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: This might work better in the electronics sister site since it’s about the quality of the cable, frequencies etc rather than programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about electronic circuitry and circuit component behaviors, not about programming.